# How to build and run C programs in sublime text 3 mac osX

Tags: c

I have installed sublime text 3 and a package control for it. Now I'm trying to build my hello-world.c but I cannot build it. When I open tools --> build with.. it offers me C++ single file but I want to build my program with C. There is no C alternative in the build systems menu.

Comment: Did you install a compiler?

Comment: No I don't think I have. How do I do that?

Comment: I suggest you give [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) a chance instead of Sublime. Nothing against ST, but if you aren't proficient at configuring your own environment yet, I think you should use a prepackaged solution.

Comment: If you still want Sublime, give [this article](https://www.mkyong.com/mac/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-mac-os-x/) a look. (I haven't tried anything of the above myself, so take it with a grain of salt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your file :

```
/* hello.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
printf ("Hello world!\n"); 
return 0;
}
```

save it something like hallo.c then compile it with gcc. So open your terminal go in your directory fileand type gcc hallo.c -o hallo and run ./hallo

To buit it on sublime plese do this :

> In Sublime, click Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc",  "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name"],
    "cmd" : ["./$file_base_name"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : false,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Or here

> Goto tools > Change build system

Anyway, I suggest you use an IDE or much better use just file & compilator.

Answer (score -2):

Sublime text is just and IDE. 
Install a C compiler and build and run using that compiler.
Try some sublime plugin compiler.